# MSBot not responding on on opening the bot. No Welcome messaged received

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, azureportal

I have created and deployed bot using a sample bot Welcome-Bot example given in Azure portal docs. This bot shows a welcome message whenever the bot is joined or started. It shows welcome message when I test it on emulator. But when I deploy it to Azure and test in Test Web App chat or Teams it doesn't show me Welcome message. It show me the welcome message when I query something, i.e. it gives two responses : one is the welcome message and other one is the reply of the query asked .

Answer (score -1):

For Microsoft Teams, you need to [create an app manifest using App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-app-studio#manifest-editor) and install in your personal scope.

For 1:1 bot conversation, `ConversationUpdate` event gets fired only for the first time. Only possible option to test welcome message is by installing your bot with a different user. For team scope this event is raised every time you install your app. You could test your welcome message in team scope if it helps.

*Note: Here is how you can [synthesize a fake event conversation update event](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-csharp/blob/1003c10c6b92e661e6e1f900c5e2434bb59a4afe/template-bot-master-csharp/src/controllers/MessagesController.cs#L234) and simulate the bot receiving it.*

Comment: Thanks Wajeed! But I am not able to understand what you have mentioned. I am using 3.welcome-user of Azure docs sample provided in this links : https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/README.md. and every time I test the bot in emulator it gives me welcome message. But I don't get a welcome message when I test it in Web through azure portal or in Teams even for the first time also. I am new to MSBots, so if you can help with an example, it would be awesome.

Comment: When you say test through Azure portal, I belive you are clicking on Teams icon which opens up chat with the bot. If yes, then this process creates draft with the bot and actual conversation is not initiated. Please [create an app manifest using App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-app-studio#manifest-editor) and install in your personal scope. Please let us know if you are facing any issue.

Comment: I am testing in "Test in Web Chat" link and also getting the link from "Get bot embed codes" and hitting the url in browser that is opening the Teams app. Both of these didn't give me the welcome message. Also I have create the bot in VS Code, can I use that in Teams and publish it on Teams or I have to strictly use App Studio to develop Team Bots ?

Comment: @Varun - Both the processes won't give you Welcome card until you type in some message to bot (hi or hello). [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-app-studio) provides UI interface for creating [App Manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema), It also makes sure that you are using right values at right place by providing help text. If you like you could [create an app manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/apps/apps-package) manually.

Comment: Thanks @Wajeed! So, I create a Bot in VSCode and not App Studio where should i keep this App Manifest file?

Comment: Bot and Microsoft Teams App manifest are two different things. Once you create App Manifest you need to [upload it to Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/apps/apps-upload#load-your-package-into-teams). If this is your first app, we recommend you to follow steps from [Get Started with Microsoft Teams App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-nodejs-app-studio).