# How do I send a 1:1 welcome message?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am looking to send a welcome message when a user installs my Teams bot.

I've looked at the Teams API documentation and have received mixed messages on whether this should be possible. I have read in various places that my bot should receive a conversationUpdate when the bot is installed, as well as reading in various issues that I will not receive such an event.

However, a bot exists which has this functionality. Hipmunk, when installed with private scope, sends me a message without being provoked further. How is this bot able to do this, and how can I replicate this functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Documentation likely conflicts because the MS Teams team is making very fast progress in implementing all of the botframework features. We also have made some pretty big changes to [activity handlers](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/activityHandler.ts)--I'm personally not aware whether or not these specific changes made it so the bot can receive the Teams ConversationUpdate or if it works because of something else.

[These tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channels-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) should fairly accurately reflect the current state of activities by channel.

I just tested a Teams bot that captures every activity with a few scenarios and here's what activity handlers fire:

**When A User Adds the Bot For the First Time (1:1 Welcome Message):**

- OnConversationUpdate
- OnTurn
- OnMembersAdded
- OnDialog

**When a Bot Is Installed to a Channel (Group Welcome Message):**

Note: These **should** also fire when a user is added to a Team (not the channel within the team) where the bot already exists, but I'm not able to test this.

- OnTurn
- OnConversationUpdate
- OnMembersAdded
- OnDialog

**When a Bot Is Messaged:**

- OnTurn
- OnMessage
- OnDialog

Here's the code I used to test this (from `bot.ts`, built from [Echo Bot Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/samples-work-in-progress/samples/javascript_typescript/02.a.echobot)):

```js
import { ActivityHandler, MessageFactory, TurnContext } from 'botbuilder';

export class MyBot extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // See https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types.
        this.onTurn(async (turnContext, next) => { await this.sendTeamsMessage('onTurn', turnContext); await next();});
        this.onMembersAdded(async (turnContext, next) => { await this.sendTeamsMessage('onMembersAdded', turnContext); await next();});
        this.onMembersRemoved(async (turnContext, next) => { await this.sendTeamsMessage('onMembersRemoved', turnContext); await next();});
        this.onEvent(async (turnContext, next) => { await this.sendTeamsMessage('onEvent', turnContext); await next();});
        this.onConversationUpdate(async (turnContext, next) => { await this.sendTeamsMessage('onConversationUpdate', turnContext); await next();});
        this.onMessage(async (turnContext, next) => { await this.sendTeamsMessage('onMessage', turnContext); await next();});
        this.onTokenResponseEvent(async (turnContext, next) => { await this.sendTeamsMessage('onTokenResponseEvent', turnContext); await next();});
        this.onUnrecognizedActivityType(async (turnContext, next) => { await this.sendTeamsMessage('onUnrecognizedActivityType', turnContext); await next();});
        this.onDialog(async (turnContext, next) => { await this.sendTeamsMessage('onDialog', turnContext); await next();});
    }

    private sendTeamsMessage = async (activityHandlerName: string, turnContext: TurnContext) => {

        const message = MessageFactory.text(`**[${activityHandlerName}]** event received`);

        await turnContext.sendActivity(message);
        console.log(`Sent: ${message.text}`)
    }
}
```

*Note: `await next()` ensures that all appropriate activity handlers can be called for a given activity instead of stopping after the first one (`onTurn`) is called.*

#### Sending a 1:1 Welcome Message

Something like this should work (from [the Core Bot Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/samples-work-in-progress/samples/javascript_typescript/13.core-bot/src/bots/dialogAndWelcomeBot.ts)):

```js
this.onMembersAdded(async (context) => {
    const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;
    for (const member of membersAdded) {
        if (member.id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
            const welcomeCard = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(WelcomeCard);
            await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [welcomeCard] });
        }
    }
});
```

We're working on writing samples with the new activity handlers, but you can [comb through this Samples Branch](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/samples-work-in-progress/samples/javascript_typescript) to get some ideas. I wrote mine in TypeScript, but it works and [there are samples in C#](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/samples-work-in-progress/samples/csharp_dotnetcore), too.

Comment: This seems to work great when I first create an app and add it. Is there a way to get notified of uninstalling and reinstalling the app, or should I only expect an event when my app is added for the first time? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, you pretty much have to create a new Web App Bot in Azure so you get a new AppId. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55181937/10860086), from Wajeed, who is on the MS Teams team.

Comment: ...I ran into that same issue while testing this, too. Instead of making a new Web App Bot every time, I had my coworkers try installing it. If you come across something easier, let me know! I didn't test using Team scope, like Wajeed mentions in that answer.

Comment: Just to update this issue, if anybody would like to test their welcome message in the future without having to install the bot with a different user, it is possible to start a new conversation with the Bot Framework Emulator which will receive the welcome message each time.