# ConversationUpdate not firing from Teams bot user added event NodeJs SDK v4

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I've been trying to implement the preview version of *Microsoft's BotFramework* for **NodeJS SDK v4** on Teams as mentioned [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/blogs/preview-release-of-the-node-js-bot-builder-v4-sdk-for-microsoft-teams). I've set up the messaging endpoint in the *Azure portal* and I'm able to receive the message events just fine.

I've tried out other bots in the Teams Store such as *Hipmunk* and they seem to be able to proactively message the users as soon as they get added on to the work space.

I've been through the documentation already and I know that I would need to work upon a `ConversationUpdate` event that fires in the event of a bot user being added to a team, but unfortunately I haven't received any such events. I've wired it up to be able to receive it because the handlers do work when I test the bot in web chat on the *Azure portal*. Is this some sort of `bug` in the *Teams client* itself or is there any alternative documentation that I've been missing. Please let me know if any code samples or further links are required to aid you in helping me as this is a pretty critical integration for me and my company.

Comment: Please have a look at existing question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55517906/how-do-i-send-a-11-welcome-message

Comment: After reviewing the link that Wajeed posted, are you still having issues? If you can post your code, I can help you troubleshoot.