# What happens to the activity if my end point is not accessible or returns a 500?

Tags: botframework

I have a Microsoft bot app that can be installed in Teams on a team.

For now, I save the tenant ID + team id in our DB when the app gets installed, via a received activity on our end point.

What happens if my prod is not up at the moment of the installation? (for whatever reason, could be an update or just a technical downtime...)

Is it lost forever? Is it retried?

Same question with a 500 error?

This activity is an example, it could be any other activity. Ex: a user is added/removed, a message has been sent etc...

Answer (score 0):

For `OnMembersAddedAsync`; unfortunately there is no retry from the Teams side, it fires and forgets.

The information in that Activity will be included in any subsequent send from Teams - so the bot can recover, if the user interacts with the bot again. Messages would just be sent when the bot recovers.

You can find a bit more info on Teams and events here:
[How do I send a 1:1 welcome message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55517906/how-do-i-send-a-11-welcome-message/55525014#55525014)